# buffer a draw graph on google maps api using ArcGIS server

Tags: google-maps-api-3, buffer, arcgis-server

I'm trying to buffer a draw graphic on google map. But seems it's not able to do the buffer.

I have a listener of drawing:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(evt) {
    event = evt;
    ...
  });
```

Then the buffer function need to buffer the this graphic:

```
function GmapBuffering() {
  gsvc = new esri.tasks.GeometryService(gsvcURL);

  //setup the buffer parameters
  var params = new esri.tasks.BufferParameters();
  params.distances = [dojo.byId("distance").value];
  params.bufferSpatialReference = gmaps.ags.SpatialReference.WEB_MERCATOR;
  params.outSpatialReference = gmaps.ags.SpatialReference.WEB_MERCATOR;
  params.unit = eval("esri.tasks.GeometryService." + dojo.byId("unit").value);
  params.geometries = [event.overlay];

  gsvc.buffer(params, function(results, err) {
    console.log(results);
    if (!err) {
      var g= results.geometries[i][j];
      g.setMap(Gmap);
      buffers.push(g);
    } else {
      alert(err.message + err.details.join(','));
    }
  });
}
```

Here's the problem, I got an error as following:

> TypeError: geom.toJson is not a function http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/?v=3.3 Line 34

Seems like **arcgis GeometryService is not able to recognize the "event" graphic**. Any ideas would be appreciate!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I got the problem solved. The error was caused by how I define the GeometryService.

Suppose we have the URL of arcgis GeometryService. In order to do buffering using Google Maps API 3, we need to define GeometryServiceas  as following:

```
var gsvcURL = "http://localhost:6080/arcgis/rest/services/Utilities/Geometry/GeometryServer";
var gsvc2 = new gmaps.ags.GeometryService(gsvcURL);
```

This example is helpful: http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn-history/r168/trunk/arcgislink/examples/buffer.html